# Input string was not in a correct format11

Tags: asp.net

When iam try to run the code iam facing the above problem

my .aspx code is

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlcatagories" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblbtncatagory" runat="server" 
            CommandArgument='<%#("Catagory_id") %>' 
            OnClick="lblbtncatagory_Click" Text='<%#Eval("catagory_name")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void lblbtncatagory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlproducts.Visible = true;
    int CategoryID = Convert.ToInt16((((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument));
    GetProducts(CategoryID);
}
```

when iam try to run the code iam facing the above problem

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format11"??

Comment: Please specify what you're trying to achieve, and what error you're getting.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Why do you use `Convert.ToInt16` to get an `int`? Either declare it as short or use `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
CommandArgument='<%#("Catagory_id") %>'
```

use

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Catagory_id") %>'
```

otherwise you try to parse the literal `"Catagory_id"` to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

plz try this i hope ur problm is solved by doing this.
int CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32((((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument));

Comment: Even if it is confusing to use  `Convert.ToInt16` to get an `int` it compiles. So this is not causing the issue. Otherwise he would not get a runtime error "Input string was not in a correct format" but a compiler error that the types are incompatible.

Comment: The error means that the string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.